# deleting small number of rows hangs in tsql database

Tags: t-sql, azure-sql-database

So I'm just trying to delete some bad data from a one of our test databases. I've identified the rows to be deleted, and have written a simple query to handle this.

However, when run, the query hangs on 4% complete, and just sits there for hours. Our databases are hosted on Azure - For this test database we're running a Standard SO with 10 DTUs.

What am I missing here?

[image: ql]

Comment: Could you do the following: highlight your query in SSMS -> press Display Estimated Execution Plan button (Ctrl+L) -> right click the plan -> Show Execution Plan XML... -> copy it (Ctrl + C) -> go to https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/ -> paste your plan's XML there -> post here the resulting link from pastetheplan ?

Comment: will do hang on

Comment: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Byf0EwXsS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might be that cascading foreign key that table [Shift Offer] has pointing to table [Availability], slows down your delete operation

Try following:

1) create nonclustered index on column [Shift Offer][availability_id_fk]
and try running your query again; see if nonclustered index speeds things up

2) if still running too long, try disable the foreign key at all (run sql command)

```
alter table [Shift Offer] nocheck constraint [paste your constraint name     
here I guess its availability_id_fk]
```

run delete command, and if succeeds and works fast, you will have to manually delete records from [Shift Offer] table, if it had any rows with `availability_id_fk` values that were deleted from [Availability] table, and  then enable foreign key back

Comment: Yep, I saw that and came to the same conclusion. I am currently building the index, and will update you.

If that's the culprit, I'll give ya a green checkmark! Thanks for the assist.

Comment: Yep that was it. Once I built the index, the query ran in all of 2 seconds.

Comment: great to know it worked!